# iPhone and iPad image size

Tags: objective-c, ios-universal-app

I tried to develop universal app, and I displayed image with size 768*1024 on iPhone 4 and I displayed the same size on iPad screen and I get good resolution for both is this normal? the same image I can use in iPhone and iPad or this happened only on simulator? whats the best size for iPhone 4 and iPad?

I appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1) image sizes are dealt with. The launch images cover the whole screen and thus give the best resolution for the devices.

Comment: Beat me to it - I was half way through writing the same thing and adding the same link +1.

Comment: Thank you Volker and Popeye for reply, but how come the same size (i.e. 768.1024) I used for both iPhone 4 and iPad and it worked with normal resolution?? I really can't understand how that worked??? or is that only work on simulator?

Comment: I assume it gets interpolated well enough. Simulator and device _should_ behave identical